# How to Change Value to Text in Table Component

Tags: ignition

Using Ignition's Table Component, when I get a value > 0, returned from my query,
I want the column "Action" to display the text "Hold".  If the value of column "Action" is LEQ 0 then I want to display the text "Crash".

Anybody know how?

What I'm getting -

[image]

What I want -

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Following Pic shows how I was able to Change the Value, of Column Action, to Text and also maintain Odd Row color scheme.

[image]